# Django mod_python logging issue

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm using Django with mod_python on remote server and need to add some logging.
I try to add some test log, in settings.py I add this code:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', filename='/home/voip_maker/django.log', filemode='a+')

logging.debug("hello world!")
logging.info("this is some interesting info!")
logging.error("this is an error!")
```

Then I restart apache and try to open my project via web,
but there are no changes in log file.

Can you please help me with this issue, how I must configure logging to get changes in log file.

Thanks very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has made logging even simpler. Please check the below docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/logging/

All you need to do is to add a dictionary to settings.py file

Comment: I was reading about django logging, but I want to create own simple logging to put to log file just some simple error messages.